# FirebaseAuth.Instance is null xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

FirebaseAuth.Instance is null in xamarin forms tried updating package removing package, unable to solve the problem

[image]

```
public async Task<bool> LoginUser(string Email, string Password)
    {            
        try
        {
            await FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(Email, Password);
            return true;
        }
        catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }   
        catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("There is no user record corresponding to this identifier");
        }            
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("There was an unkown Error."); 
        }   
    }
```

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images.  Take the time to format your post so that it is readable

Comment: It seems a known issue here , check this link if it helps: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/223.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT Checked but still unable to solve from a month and still trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

1. install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base
2. include google-services.json with the 'GoogleServicesJson' build action
3. invoke Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this); in MainActivity.onCreate() method.